# How do I access my runserver after compile my django script from SSH?

Tags: django

I ran my script from SSH. On my browser, I tried to go to that specific IP:Port and it doesn't display?

```
python manage.py runserver
or
python manage.py runserver 182.110.213.173:8005
```

Answer (score 0):

**Don't use the dev server to make your site publicly available, it's insecure.** If you publicly available, then [deploy it properly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/).

If you are still testing, another option is to use an SSH tunnel.

```
ssh -L 9000:localhost:8000 user@yourserver.com
```

Now, run the dev server on the remote machine:

```
python manage.py runserver 8000
```

Now port 8005 on the remote machine is forwarded to port 9000 on your local machine, and you can access your site at http://localhost:9000 as long as the ssh tunnel is open.